# Amazon SES: double dot

Tags: codeigniter, smtp, amazon-ses

I'm experiencing some weird behavior on Amazon SES.
I have a webapp that sends html emails using SES, recently i've noticed that some images dont load after receiving the email.

The images are stored in S3.

After inspection i've noticed just in some cases that the url of the image is being modified.
Taking this example: the url of the image is http://example.com/image_name.png, after sending the email the URL of the image become http://example.com/image_name..png (notice the double dot before the extension).

If i send the same email to gmail and hotmail, i experience this issue, but with different images. Gmail puts double dot in image_2.png and hotmail puts it in image_1.png.

Im using Codeigniter email class to send the emails via SMTP.

Comment: The different behavior per provider seems to indicate an issue with the code you are using to assemble/send the email rather than the targeted service - could you provide the (eventually abbreviated) assembling/sending code fragment accordingly?

Comment: After trying every config option of the codeigniter mail class, i tried adding `'crlf' => "\r\n"` and it seems to fix this.

Although it just happens if i'm sending the email with SES smtp. I tried with other smtp host and didnt have to add this config option.

Comment: I see, so by _send the same email to gmail and hotmail_ you meant these providers as recipients for an email sent via SMTP over SES still, not as SMTP providers for email sent elsewhere, right?

Answer (score 6):

Adding `'crlf' => "\r\n"` fixed the issue with the following config:

`/aaplication/config/email.php`

```
<?php

$config['protocol']         = 'smtp';
$config['mail_smtp_secure'] = 'TLS';
$config['smtp_host']        = 'ssl://email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com';
$config['smtp_port']        = 465;
$config['smtp_user']        = 'user';
$config['smtp_pass']        = 'password';
$config['charset']          = 'UTF-8';
$config['mailtype']         = 'html';
$config['newline']          = "\r\n";
$config['crlf']             = "\r\n";
$config['wordwrap']         = TRUE;
$config['smtp_timeout']     = '20';
$config['bcc_batch_mode']   = TRUE;
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

For CI's email class to work with Amazon SES, the newline needs to be set to `\r\n`, as noted in the comments above.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526043/codeigniter-smtp-email-with-amazon-ses) and answer.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was solved when we used the CodeIgnitor Amazon SES library : https://github.com/joelcox/codeigniter-amazon-ses